# Record keyboard/mouse macros for games

Tags: ubuntu, macros

I want to record a keyboard/mouse macro for automatically playing repetitive flash games.  The programs I'm familiar with xnee/gnee/pnee and xmacro don't work under Ubuntu 10.04.

(Xnee gives "Xnee failed due to bad data received from RECORD extension" for version 3.02, which is a known issue which I haven't found a solution for, and xmacro just plain doesn't work...)

Are there any other methods I could use besides these two programs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[evtest-capture](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~whot/evtest/tree/evtest-capture.txt) can read the events from the underlying input device and produce output that can be turned into a program that will inject those events back into uinput.